# Why P(E|H) equal to L(H|E) in Bayes's rule?

Tags: bayesian

In the following Bayes's rule,

$$
P(H|E)=\frac{P(E|H)\cdot P(H)}{P(E)} 
$$

Many resources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) deduce that the *probability* of E given H equal to the *likelihood* of H given E or $P(E|H) = L(H|E)$.

I wonder why it is so? From my understanding the $P(E|H)$ is the distribution of **E** given **H** while $L(H|E)$ is the distribution of **H** given **E**. Why the distribution of different variable is equal to each other?

Thank you in advance for every answers!

Comment: They are not the same, but they are proportional.  If you have a possibly biased coin with probability of heads $p$, flip it five times and observe two heads and three tails then the probability of that is $10p^2(1-p)^3$, while if you observe Heads, Tails, Tails, Tails, Heads then the probability is $p^2(1-p)^3$ - a tenth of the previous result.  But intuitively the likelihood for $p$ given either way of recording observations is the same in both cases.  The good news is that it does not matter which you use: when $P(E  \mid H)$ is $10$ times higher, so too is $P(E)$ and it all cancels out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$P(E|H)$is what you mentioned the distribution of $E$ given $H$.

The likelihood is the same distribution $P(E|H)$ but viewed as function of the variable $H$, i.e. you want to check how the $P(E|H)$ changes as you change $H$, in order to find the most probable $H$ that generated the data. That's why you can write $P(E|H)= L(H|E)$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. So, the likelihood is the distribution P(E|H) while H is also another variable.

Comment: Yes, for example let $E$ be a Bernoulli random variable then it has distribution $p(E|p) = p^{E}(1-p)^{1-E}$, where for convenience denote $H=p$. Then you can see how $p(E|H)$ changes as you change $H$.

Answer (score 4):

The simple reason that they are the same is that $L(H\mid E)$ is *defined* to be $P(E \mid H)$